# What's the recommended way to handle naming collisions with the PK column?

Tags: naming-convention

I have a data field "Shipment ID" which is a `VARCHAR(18)` from a number of different vendors. This is going into a table `shipment` with a surrogate PK `shipment_id`.

I'm trying to figure out the best way to name this column. Our conventions say:

1. Only PKs or FKs can end in `_id`.
2. PKs are `tablename_id`. So a table `hello_world` would have a PK of `hello_world_id`.
3. table and columns are `lowercase_with_underscores`
4. nothing about name collisions (if I get a good answer here, I'll make sure it's added to the style guide.)

I know it doesn't follow [this awesome answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4703155/1354930), but that's what we've got

I can't use the "Shipment ID" field as a PK because it's not guaranteed to be unique or even exist. Plus it is a string and I am not a fan of string PKs.

I don't really like `shipment_name` or `vendor_shipment_id`. What do you guys use in cases like this?

Comment: "vendor_reference" perhaps, although it isn't a reference to the vendor, but the vendor's reference to the transaction.  If you have vendor_id to identify the vendor, then "vendor_reference" won't create confusion.  We tend to call any table key column "id", although we also have "staffid" in the staff table and "staff_id" in some other tables (for the same id).

Comment: @RDFozz Actually I don't mind `shipment_id_from_vendor` all that much. I'm just surprised that I didn't think of it. I've also added another line to the conventions for more clarity: we use PKs are `tablename_id`.

Comment: "Rubber ducking" http://dilbert.com/strip/2017-05-28

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the stated rules, `shipment_id_from_vendor` would be better than `vendor_shipment_id` (doesn't end in `_id`, so not expected to be a PK/FK field).

Generally, for me, a name collision would mean that one or both names require a better definition, to clarify whey they're distinct values. Even near-collisions should be avoided: If you have a requirements date and a request date, using the names `req_date` and `request_date` is not particularly helpful; someone may be looking for the request date, see `req_date`, and assume that they've found what they wanted. `requirements_date` may be much longer to type, but it's immediately clear what it is, and no one's going to mix it up with `request_date`.

That said, there's no universal solution to this. I have no issue with long table and column names, if that's what's needed to make them clear; other people would insist brevity is key and make the two columns from the previous paragraph `reqr_date` and `rqst_date`.